# get common elements from a result which consists of more than 1 array in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to fetch common elements from multiple arrays. The no. of arrays resulted would keep changing depending upon the no. of tags in array a[].

As a first step, my query and result I get is as shown below:

```
let a=["Men","Women","Accessories"]
let c=(for i in a
       Let d=Concat("Tags/",i)
       return d)

for i in c
   let m=(for y in outbound i TC 
          return y._key)
   return m
```

and result I get is:

```
[
  [
    "C1",
    "C5",
    "C7",
    "C3"
  ],
  [
    "C2",
    "C5",
    "C6",
    "C4"
  ],
  [
    "C7",
    "C5",
    "C6"
  ]
]
```

From this result, I want only common element as a result i.e "C5" (here).

How can I get that?

Comment: Do you know the number of tags ahead of time? If so you could end your query with something like.  `let D= [["C1","C5","C7","C3"],["C2","C5","C6","C4"],["C7","C5","C6"]]
return INTERSECTION(D[0],D[1],D[2])`

Comment: You don't need to know the number in advance, you can use APPLY() to make this work with a dynamic amount of nested arrays, e.g. `APPLY("INTERSECTION", D)`. See docs: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Functions/Miscellaneous.html#apply

Answer (score 0):

This question has also been asked and answered on [github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/6793).

The function INTERSECTION() returns the intersection of all specified arrays and APPLY() is used to pass a dynamic amount of nested arrays.

The query

```
let D = [["C1","C5","C7","C3"],["C2","C5","C6","C4"],["C7","C5","C6"]] 

RETURN APPLY("INTERSECTION", D)
```

results in:

```
[
  [
    "C5"
  ]
]
```